# At runtime add columns in raw SQL from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, sqlclient, dynamicquery

I have an SQL query in which the `WHERE` clause will be decided at runtime. It can be any combination of columns with `OR` and `AND` operators. Stored procedures are restricted in this database, so raw SQL will be used.

Get ris OData from postman can be any one of the below.

```
eq  Equals          /Employees?$filter=Name eq 'John'
ne  Does not equal  /Employees?$filter=Name ne 'John'
gt  Greater than    /Employees?$filter=Age gt 15
lt  Less than       /Employees?$filter=Age lt 15
ge  Greater than or equal to /Employees?$filter=Age ge 15
and /Employees?$filter=Name eq 'John' and Age gt 65
or  /Employees?$filter=Age gt 65 or Age lt 11
not /Employees?$filter=not(Name eq 'John')
```

Then a `SqlDataReader` will be used to fetch data from the database after the query is constructed and executed.

```cs
public ActionResult Get(Columns columns =null)
{
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    str.Append("select firstNmae,lastname,gender,city from dbo.customer where ");

    if (columns != null)
    {
        if (columns.firstName != null || columns.firstName != "")
        {
            str.Append(String.Format("firstname = '{0}' ", columns.Name));
        }

        if (columns.lastName != null || columns.lastName != "")
        {
            str.Append(String.Format("lastName = '{0}' ", columns.lastName));
        }
    }
}
```

How can I include the above with this SQL?

```sql
select firstName, lastname, gender, city 
from dbo.customer 
where + columns which comes at runtime 1 or more with or and conditions
```

Comment: fwiw, **I would not do this**, as what you're talking about is crazy vulnerable to sql injection attacks, and will make it stupid-easy for an attacker (or even benign user by accident) to run arbitrary SQL of their own choosing, including completely separate UPDATE and DELETE queries.

Comment: i how about using entity frameworks query builder instead?

Comment: If you are going to do something like this, make sure you have a very specific language and that you are carefully parsing it.  Don't allow any column name; restrict it to the correct ones.  Create a precise grammar, and only allow constructs that match the grammar. Then get someone with hacking experience to pound your system as hard as they can.  SQL injection is insidious; it's easy to provide a malevolent actor with the _keys to the kingdom_

Comment: "Stored procedures are restricted in this database" whose brainwave was that, and what benefit did they think it provided?

Comment: @Charlieface, one of our app architects prohibit the use of stored procedures to help ensure the application is "cloud native".  It's madness.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I also don't want to do this due to SQL Injection attacks, as SP can't be created am looking for other ways, do achieve this safely.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann You mean pass Raw SQL in dbcontext context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("Select ") than how do I append runtime columns which can be of any combinations and conditions.

Comment: @Charlieface my request for SP was denied, raw sql will be used for Get API's.

Comment: @Dan Guzman Its not in my hand for SP, so raw sql is provided.

Comment: no, by "use the query builder" i meant to _use the query builder_ so you don't ever have to write SQL again. you know, the exact opposite of running raw SQL through entity framework. also: @Charlieface - stored procedures are at least 20 years outdated, and even if done right, a source of constant headaches at best.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann While I agree with the general idea (especially in this case) that a query builder or an ORM would be ideal for basic CRUD or for dynamic queries, there are many cases which that can't cover, and many types of databases where complex stuff needs to go in a procedure. Banning them completely is nonsensical, they can be maintained in source control and can be backed up, so there's no reason to idealogocially avoid them completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When building SQL like this, you have to be **very careful** about how you do it. It's stupid-easy to accidently end up wide open to SQL injection issues.

To do it **safely** (and this is one of those areas that's too important to do wrong, even in learning/practice/proof-of-concept/private work), there are two things you MUST do:

1. Pre-validate column names (and operators) vs what's actually in the database. You can do this by running quick (safe) SQL statements with the `sys.columns` view, or by including the set of allowed columns directly in your application. Then, provide the text for those items yourself, rather than directly from the user input.
2. Use query parameters instead of string concatenation for the filter data.

In this way, no user-provided text ever becomes part of the final SQL statement. *This is important!*

What I will **NOT** do here is speak to how you parse the `columns` conditions. *This is not a code writing service*, and the grammar described here will quickly get waaaaay beyond what you expect, akin to a fully-functional SQL parser.

But once that is done, you need to end up with something like this:

```
public ActionResult Get(Columns columns =null)
{
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("select firstNmae,lastname,gender,city from dbo.customer where 1=1 ");
    var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
    SqlParameter p;

    // Assuming you already extracted your columns details
    //  from the input into separate variables used below
    //  (again: not a code writing service, you'll need to do this part)

    if (NameFilter.Length > 0)
    {
        str.Append(" AND Name = @Name");
        // use actual database types/lengths here
        p = new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20);
        p.Value = firstNameFilter;
        parameters.Add(p);
    }

    if (AgeFilter.Length > 0)
    {
        //simplified
        var opMap = new Dictionary<string, string>() {{"lt", "<"}, {"le","<="},{"eq","="},{"ne","<>"},{"gt",">"},{"ge",">="}};
        var op = opMap[AgeOperator];

        str.Append($" AND Age {op} @Age");
        // use actual database types/lengths here
        p = new SqlParameter("@Age", SqlDbType.Int);
        p.Value = Convert.ToInt32(AgeFilter);
        parameters.Add(p);
    }

    // ...

    using var conn = new SqlConnection("connection string here");
    using var cmd = new SqlCommand(str.ToString(), conn);
    foreach(var parameter in parameters)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
    }
    conn.Open();
    using var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();    

    // do something with your reader ...

}
```

Note in the above code, text parsed from the `columns` input is **ONLY** ever used via an `SqlParameter` object's `.Value` property. All the other text used in the SQL command is pulled from string literals in the code.

To focus in on one of the examples:

```
if (AgeFilter.Length > 0)
{
    //simplified
    var opMap = new Dictionary<string, string>() {{"lt", "<"}, {"le","<="},{"eq","="},{"ne","<>"},{"gt",">"},{"ge",">="}};
    var op = opMap[AgeOperator];

    str.Append($" AND Age {op} @Age");
    // use actual database types/lengths here
    p = new SqlParameter("@Age", SqlDbType.Int);
    p.Value = Convert.ToInt32(AgeFilter);
    parameters.Add(p);
}
```

In the above code, after parsing the `columns` input we determine there is a filter on the `Age` column via the `if()` conditional statement.

Inside this `if()` block we don't just accept the user-provided column name. Instead, we provide the column name separately.

Likewise, we allowed the user to tell us which operator to use, but we did not accept what was provided directly. Rather we transformed that to a known-good value via the `opMap` dictionary.

Finally, we did accept exactly what the user gave us for the actual `age` value... but only included it in the query via a parameter, so it remains quarantined from the SQL command statement.

Then we put it all together ourselves, so we control the structure of the result.

*This is the only safe way to build dynamic queries.*

Comment: Thanks for the ideas but at run time I don't know in which combinations the columns will come so have to write so many if conditions. (or and)

Comment: @Dave "have to write so many if conditions". Yes. Yes you will. The only other safe option is to define a class with fields for column, operator, filter value, and boolean pre-condition, and iterate through the collection. But it's still on you to replace the column name text, so it's still effectively a set of checks on every possible column. There is no other safe way.

Comment: Joel Coehoorn Thanks